# EFCore + Linq, how to Select specify users first, then rest of them?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have list of users are currently online:

```
List<int> onlineUsers = _connectedUsersEntity.GetOnlineIds();
```

then im making request:

```
var profiles = await _cnx.Users
                .OrderBy(p => onlineUsers.Any(z => z == p.Id))
                .ThenBy(p => p.Id)
                .Select(p => new { p.Id, p.DisplayName, p.ProfilePhoto })
                .Skip(request.Skip)
                .Take(request.Take)
                .ToListAsync();
```

I want to have:

```
//skip 0 take 3
{"user1":"online"}
{"user3":"online"}
{"user2":"offline"}

//then next call skip 3, take 3
{"user4":"offline"}
{"user5":"offline"}
{"user6":"offline"}
```

What i have:

```
{"user1":"online"}
{"user2":"offline"}
{"user3":"online"}
```

How to make correct linq statement for that ?

Comment: I have implemented [PaginatedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in a Project. I would check that out and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```cs
var profiles = await _cnx.Users
    .OrderBy(p => onlineUsers.Contains(p.Id) ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(p => p.Id)
    .Skip(request.Skip)
    .Take(request.Take)
    .Select(p => new { p.Id, p.DisplayName, p.ProfilePhoto })
    .ToListAsync();
```